# How to detect Win8/Metro from Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How does one detect that the environment is Windows 8 Metro application from Javascript?

UPDATE: To clarify, my Javascript code runs both on any browser and as part of an Win8 application. Since Win8 applications impose security restrictions for JS code, I want to detect when the code is running in Win8 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering myself:

One way to detect this is to check the existence of some MS-specific objects or namespaces. One of them is Windows. For example:

```
if (typeof Windows != "undefined") {
  // Running in Win8 app
} else {
  // Running in a browser
}
```

Comment: You could also try detecting the presence of WinRT namespaces (which are projected as objects in JS) - most notably the root `Windows` namespace.

Comment: Can someone see what `({}).toString.call(Windows)` is?  It might be a more robust detect.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use:

```
WorkerNavigator.useragent
```

property to detect it

Comment: What exactly do you propose? Is the existence of that property a good test for Win8/Metro or should one look at the contents of useragent? Doesn't sound reliable.

Comment: Well, yea property test is by par a better way than useragent comparatively

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
var isWinJS = !!window.Windows && /^ms-appx:/.test(location.href);
```